# JWT Authentication in StepZen

Tags: authentication, graphql, oauth, jwt, saleor

I have two headless backend services: *Saleor* and *Strapi*, which provide with GraphQL API for e-commerce development. The problem was to find a service, which can stitch two( or more ) GraphQL schemas so that I can have access to them by one endpoint. Such service is [StepZen](https://stepzen.com). Normally when trying to fetch requests on StepZen you would have to do it with

```
{
"Authorization": "apikey <apikey>"
}
```

as a header. And it would also work. But when you have some fields in schemas you stitching which Require JWT authentication you need somehow to pass in **Authorization** header Bearer token. In ***StepZen*** there is an opportunity to forward headers, so theoretically I could use that to forward **Authorization**  header to fields, because StepZen also provides ***JWT Authentication*** when making your request instead of using API-Key. And **THAT** is the main problem(failing to **access** StepZen with only Bearer Token).

As it stays in documentation I changed my config.yaml file accordingly:

```
deployment:
  identity:
    jwksendpoint: https://<MY-DOMAIN>/.well-known/jwks.json
access:
  policies:
    - type: Query
      policyDefault:
        condition: '?$jwt'
```

Unfortunately trying after this accessing the endpoint with the Bearer Token as the value of **Authorization** header like this:

```
{"Authorization" : "Bearer <token>"}
```

got me always the same 401 error from StepZen, **NOT** Saleor( *Unauthorized: missing or not allowed* ), which means that none of my requests reach its endpoint. I am totally lost, because I tried already all combinations from the [StepZen docs](https://stepzen.com/docs) of config.yaml file and none of that worked. I would be very happy if someone could explain me what the problem is.